# AppScript Dynamic Email Reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Hi I need help on how to reference the "to" to a cell data, I wanted the data to be dynamic at some  point. Please see my script below

```
function Email() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").activate();
var message = {
to: 'b9',
cc: "email@sampleemail.com",
subject: "Test Email",
body: "Hi,\\n\\nPls review this email.\\n\\nThank you,\\nKate",
name: "Kate",
attachments: \[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Email Subject")\]
}`
```

Comment: `GmailApp.sendEmail(sheet.getRange(message.to).getValue(),...`

Comment: @Cooper `sheet` isn't defined. Perhaps replace `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").activate();` with `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email")`

Comment: Yes but I think it delivers the message.

Comment: You are probably right. In my case, I get a `ReferenceError: sheet is not defined` for the "GmailApp" line of code.